# How to escape a string with a quote on the end

Tags: sql, vb.net

Does somebody know how to escape the following quote within the string correctly?

PDM-40-100'

The string has an quote on the right end.

Comment: Use [sql-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)

Comment: Post more code of where your attempt at using this string is going wrong

Answer (score 1):

In SQL escaping (') can be achieved with (''). User `PDM-40-100''` instead of `PDM-40-100'`.

If varX= PDM-40-100' then you can use `Replace(varX,"'","''")`

Comment: Please let us know if you are facing any more difficulties with this query.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample for 1 string. With this logic, you can escape all rows in table.

```
Declare @string as varchar(12)='PDM-40-100'''  
Select left(@string, len(@string)-1)
```